# Is reinterpret cast to derived class without additional members OK?

Tags: c++, c++17

In my code below, I do a non-polymorphic reinterpret cast from a base class to its derived. There are no additional members in the derived class, so I expect that memory layout and the functionality of the derived is exactly the same as the base class, with the difference that I only introduced a new type (which is my intention). Is this correct and portable C++? When not, is there a correct and portable way to realize this?

I would like to use the `||` operator for serializing for both input and output. This is nice, because then the definition of serialize in and serialize out can be shared. (I think Boost is doing this as well). If I want to do this with an object that derives from `std::streambuf`, then it is a problem to make a distinction between input and output, because `td::streambuf` represents both. To get around this, I’ve constructed something like the code below. Two types are introduced: `ostreambuf_t` and `istreambuf_t`. The dirty work to cast is done in the `ut_cast()` and `in_cast()` cast operators. I added a size check with the `static_assert`.

```
template<typename B>
class ostreambuf_t
    : public B
{
public:
    template<typename T >
    ostreambuf_t& operator||(T v)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(ostreambuf_t<B>) == sizeof(B));
    …}
…}

template<typename B>
class istreambuf_t
    : public B
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    istreambuf_t& operator||(T& v)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(istreambuf_t<B>) == sizeof(B));
    …}
…}

…
template <typename B> inline ostreambuf_t<B>& out_cast(B& sbuf)
{ return reinterpret_cast<ostreambuf_t<B>&>(sbuf); }
template <typename B> inline istreambuf_t<B>&  in_cast(B& sbuf)
{ return reinterpret_cast<istreambuf_t<B>&>(sbuf); }

// example usage:
    std::stringbuf sbuf;
    ostreambuf_t<std::stringbuf>&
        osbuf(out_cast<std::stringbuf>(sbuf));
    float f = 1.;
    double d = 2.;
    long double l = 3.;
    osbuf || f || d || l;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but it might be better not to "invent" notations (like using `||` this way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a UB. The Standard reads (N4659, *[basic.lval]/8*)

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type similar (as defined in 7.5) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std::byte` type.

In your code you are trying to access the object of type `std::stringbuf` through a glvalue of type `ostreambuf_t<std::stringbuf>`, and no bullet in the quote above applies.

Additionally, [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) on `reinterpret_cast` reads:

> Performing a class member access that designates a non-static data member or a non-static member function on a glvalue that does not actually designate an object of the appropriate type - such as one obtained through a `reinterpret_cast` - results in undefined behavior: [examples]

Why not to simply store a reference to `std::stringbuf` inside `(i/o)streambuf_t`?

Comment: Simply store a reference to std::stringbuf inside (i/o)streambuf_t does very likely satisfy my need. I'm gonna try this.

Comment: Yes, this is a working solution. I've got it working.