# Is it safe to cast a class to a derived class that just adds additional functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have a class that contains a lot a data. Depending on the situation I need to output this data in different ways. I want the output routines for each of those situations separated and I want to keep the base class clean of that.

Is it absolutely safe to cast to a derived class that does NOT add any data members but just non-virtual functions?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base {
public:
  Base() { printf("Base()\n"); }
  
  double A = 3.14;
  int B = 5;
  int C = 42;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
  Derived1() { printf("Derived1()\n"); }
  
  void DoStuff() {
    // doing stuff with base class's data
    printf("  A = %.4f\n", A);
    printf("  B = %d\n", B);
    printf("  C = %d\n", C);
  }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
  Derived2() { printf("Derived2()\n"); }

  void DoStuff() {
    // doing stuff with base class's data in a slightly different way
    printf("  A = %.4f, B = %d, C = %d\n", A, B, C);
  }
};

class OtherBase {
public:
  OtherBase() { printf("OtherBase()\n"); }
  int D = 10;
};

class Derived3 : virtual public OtherBase, virtual public Base {
public:
  Derived3() { printf("Derived3()\n"); }
  
  void SomeFunction() {
    A = 6.28;
    B = 1;
    C = 500;
    printf("Done some other stuff.\n");
  }
};

int main() {
  printf("Base class\n\n");
  Base* Instance = new Base();
  printf("Cast to Derived1:\n");
  static_cast<Derived1*>(Instance)->DoStuff();
  printf("Cast to Derived2:\n");
  static_cast<Derived2*>(Instance)->DoStuff();
  
  printf("\nOther class derived from base class\n\n");
  Derived3* Instance2 = new Derived3();
  Instance2->SomeFunction();
  printf("Cast to Derived1:\n");
  static_cast<Derived1*>(static_cast<Base*>(Instance2))->DoStuff();
  printf("Cast to Derived2:\n");
  static_cast<Derived2*>(static_cast<Base*>(Instance2))->DoStuff();
  printf("c-style cast to Derived1:\n");
  ((Derived1*) Instance2)->DoStuff();
  printf("c-style cast to Derived2:\n");
  ((Derived2*) Instance2)->DoStuff();
  return 0;  
}
```

The part where class "Derived3" (that has virtual inheritance of "Base") is cast to "Base" first and then to "Derived1"/"Derived2" does not look very good to me but I know how c-style casts are frowned upon in the c++ community. In this small example however, the c-style cast are compiling and working nicely:

I know there is the issue with multiple inheritance where a cast to one of the base classes can have a different pointer address then the inherited class it was cast from. So I understand that it might be too dangerous to rely on it.

Are the static casts I did in the example at the top safe?

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not a problem here. But I'm fairly sure this is UB regardless, though I'm not sure if it's going to cause problems in practice.

Comment: you're casting base object to derived object should use dynamic_cast it is not safe ?

Comment: @Anis Belaid: "you're casting base object to derived object ?" That's right. Just to access the functions provided by the derived object. As in the example, the particular derived object is designed for that purpose.

Comment: I think that is not safe , you should use a dynamic_cast to make sure it will work

Comment: @bugblatterbeast On the surface, it would seem you would be better off using templates instead of what you came up with using inheritance.

Comment: @AnisBelaid No, `dynamic_cast` is not allowed here and would not help even if it was allowed.

Comment: @Anis Belaid: Sure, a dynamic cast would do a runtime check... Still, why would it be unsafe? Non-virtual function are stored separately from data, right? I'm not sure, but I think a cast from base to a derived class that just adds non-virtual functions should be OK.

Comment: Inheritance, where only non-virtual functions are added in the derived class (and no data members), is not good. Consider using global (or namespace-level) functions instead of making them members of the derived classes.

Comment: Why do you think calling a member function on a non-existent derived-class object is better than just using a free function? I mean, why would you even consider doing this instead of just `doStuff1(instance); doStuff2(instance);`?

Comment: @AnisBelaid First, `dynamic_cast` is not allowed when there are no virtual functions around. Second, if it worked, it would return `nullptr` in this case.

Comment: @bugblatterbeast then use a reinterpret_cast in that case if you're sure that you data match but I am not so sure

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54378044/is-reinterpret-cast-to-derived-class-without-additional-members-ok) is a bit more convoluted but the answer provides a quote from the standard for why this is UB.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie mmh sorry, I can't follow. I have an object that stores the data. And I want to output the data of exactly the same object in different ways. I don't understand how a template would help me with that. Maybe I'm missing the point, but it's not just different data in the same format.

Comment: @Eugene@Useless good point

Comment: @bugblatterbeast Your `Base` class is written so that it is not meant to be derived from.  It has no virtual functions, and it has no virtual destructor.   If you're using public inheritance as a means of writing less code, that is not what the purpose of inheritance is.  A template class or function, where you feed it as a template argument a class that prints out from Base what it needs to print makes more sense (to me).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah, you meant as a template ARGUMENT. Now I understand. Yes, that totally makes sense to me. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't safe. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Static casting to a derived type is safe only when the dynamic type of the object is that derived type (or a further derived type).

Comment: I do think that the idea that Eugene and Useless provided to use global functions is a much smarter choice then the idea I had in mind. Still, I don't see what is making it unsave and what would lead to undifined behaviour. I admit, I have just thought of classes as addresses to bulks of memory. And since non-virtual functions stored apart from data, I don't understand what would go wrong technically. Sure, I accept the answer, but I would feel a lot better if anybody could explain what exactly would lead to undefined behaviour (I still need to study the link that 1201ProgramAlarm provided).

Comment: @bugblatterbeast `Still, I don't see what is making it unsave and what would lead to undifined behaviour` It's the same thing that makes anything UB in C++: The rules of the language. `I don't understand what would go wrong technically` When behaviour of the program is undefined, anything and everything could go wrong.

Comment: That's ofc a valid point and I am sorry for bother you. Still I can never be satisfied with just accepting rules without understanding them. It's surely just my point of view, but I think that's what makes a good scientist.
EDIT: On review that comment could be misleading. What I mean is I can accept but I can't understand the rules from your explanations and it would help me a lot if someone could explain them technically.

Comment: To me the derived class is just one bulk of data that contains all the variables - which in this case should be exactly at the same offsets as in the base class and another bulk of memory for the non-virtual functions which is shared for all the instances of the derived class. If those assumptions are correct and I take the memory of the base class and use it as the derived class, I don't see the problem. I don't want to argue. I believe you. As an experienced C and Assembler programmer, I just want to understand.

Comment: @bugblatterbeast You are right that the derived class object has the same memory layout as the base in your case. That's why your code *may* happen to work despite the UB. What can break it in practice are compiler optimizations. You were trying to outsmart the compiler, which is not a good idea.

Comment: @Eugene That is a reasonable concern. I can understand that. Thank you for pointing it out.